# Is there a function similar MATLAB's 'impixelinfo()' available in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I'm searching for a function in OpenCV that is similar to `impixelinfo()` in MATLAB.

`impixelinfo()` shows you

1. the location of the pixel `(x, y)`  and
2. the pixel intensity of your cursor hovering in the image,

   like:

[impixelinfo() in matlab shows you this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5E6f.png)

Is there any implementation of this in OpenCV already? Does anyone have a personal version of it created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat img;

void
CallBackFunc(int event,int x,int y,int flags,void* userdata)
{
   if(event==EVENT_MOUSEMOVE){
      cout << "Pixel (" << x << ", " << y << "): " << img.at<Vec3b>(y,x) << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   // Read image from file 
   img=imread("demo.jpg");

   // Check it loaded
   if(img.empty()) 
   { 
      cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   //Create a window
   namedWindow("ImageDisplay",1);

   // Register a mouse callback
   setMouseCallback("ImageDisplay",CallBackFunc,nullptr);

   // Main loop
   while(true){
      imshow("ImageDisplay",img);
      waitKey(50);
   }
}
```

[image]

As a result of the helpful comments, I (hopefully) improved the code and now handle grayscale images, and have also set the RGB ordering more akin to how  non-OpenCV aficionados might expect it - i.e. RGB rather than BGR. The updated function is below:

```
void
CallBackFunc(int event,int x,int y,int flags,void* userdata)
{
   if(event==EVENT_MOUSEMOVE){
      // Test if greyscale or color
      if(img.channels()==1){
         cout << "Grey Pixel (" << x << ", " << y << "): " << (int)img.at<uchar>(y,x) << endl;
      } else {
         cout << "RGB Pixel (" << x << ", " << y << "): " << (int)img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2] << "/" << (int)img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] << "/" << (int)img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0] << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I should probably check the image has 3 channels and handle greyscale images slightly differently. Maybe later...

Comment: That looks good! Tnx. And if I want to see intensity values from grayscale image I change: img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)  to  img.at<char>(y,x)... but why then I see strange characters instead of integer from 0-255??

Comment: You need to cast the `char` to `int` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Btw if you want to match the behaviour of `impixelinfo`, you may want to flip the order of the B and R channels when displaying their values. As you already know, the order of the pixel layout is reversed. Also going to grayscale is easy. In the event handler, just check the number of channels in the image and adjust the template resolution when using `at` accordingly. `cv::Mat` has a `channels()` method. Regardless, awesome work. +1`.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback - I have updated and hopefully improved the code a little to reflect your comments.